# yii2 Validation not working

Tags: validation, model, yii2, rule, yii2-validation

I need to validate a value from another table both of them field type `decimal`

if amount(model 1) moreover available(model2 DATA  selected)

model 1
rule

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
           [['amount'], 'checkAvailable','skipOnEmpty' => false],
    ];
}
```

custom validation function

```
  public function checkAvailable($attribute, $params)
{
    $caid = $this->capex_budget_id;
    $available = Capexbudget::find()
            ->select(['available'])
            ->where('id = :caid', [':caid' => $caid])
            ->all();   // select amount from Capexbudget where id = $caid 
    if ($this->amount > $available){
     $this->addError('amount', 'not enough');
    }
}
```

i can got a data available from Capexbudget where ID that i select

here are the query logs

[image]

but validation not working it not compare value between $this->amount and $available
what i missing please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're selecting **all** records matching your `where` conditions here:

```
    $available = Capexbudget::find()
        ->select(['available'])
        ->where('id = :caid', [':caid' => $caid])
        ->all();  // HERE
```

You should change function `all()` to `one()`, to get **one** record.
Second thing is, if you're using `all()` or `one()`, that methods returns **object**, not **value**.

To make it work, you should change `if` statement to:

```
if ($this->amount > $available->available){   //here, compare to attribute `available`
```

Comment: oh, you answer is working for me.
thanks you very nuch . sir